# PDO fetch / fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Not new to PHP, but only a day old to PDO. Surely I am doing something wrong here.

```
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $query->execute(array('username' => $username,'password' => sha1($password)));
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (count($result) > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['user']['who']        = $result[0]['who'];
        $_SESSION['user']['email']  = $result[0]['email'];
        $_SESSION['user']['username']   = $result[0]['username'];
        echo REFRESH;
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Invalid username / password.";  
    }
```

the only way I can declare those `$_SESSIONS` properly is if I use `$result[0]['fieldName'];` How can I just access it via `$result['fieldName'];` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), as the documentation says, retrieves an array of all fetch data simultaneously.  Since you are using `FETCH_ASSOC`, an array of associative arrays is fetched.  If you know for certain that only one column is being returned or are only interested in the first column returned, just use `fetch`.  Otherwise you have to iterate over the `fetchAll` results or do what you've done.

Comment: Alright, so what would the **proper** test case be for it not returning anything if I use just `fetch`? First thought would be `(!empty($result)) ? //log in : //invalid`

Comment: `fetch` will return a falsy value if there are no rows.  You could also check `rowCount`.  Either `if ($query->rowCount)` or `if (!$row = $result->fetch())` will do.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
foreach( $result as $row )  
{  
    $_SESSION['user']['who']  = $row['who'];
    .... and so on
}
```

Comment: Seems silly to use `foreach` when it overwrites the same variable each time, and when you know there's only one element in the array to begin with.

Comment: True - go with @explosion pills approach.