# PHP PDO fetchAll then json_encode doesn't work

Tags: php, json

I have a strange issue. I have a simple PHP script that uses PDO to get all countries from a database then returns the result as json. When I use the fetch function instead of fetchAll everything works as expected. When I print_r the data is there.

Doesn't work:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
if($stmt = $_db->prepare($sql))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    header("content-type:application/json");

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();

}
```

Works:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
if($stmt = $_db->prepare($sql))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    header("content-type:application/json");

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();

}
```

Results of print_r:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Afghanistan
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Åland Islands
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Albania
    )
....
[248] => Array
    (
        [id] => 249
        [name] => Zimbabwe
    )

)
1
```

Comment: What does the first code do? Which piece of code is that `print_r` from? Is it the same in both?

Comment: fetch() is supposed to only return the next result row...

Comment: As you can see, fetch() and fetchAll() return different sets of data.  It's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: I should have been clearer with my question. I understand that fetch returns the next row, this works perfectly when I use json_encode and return the data. I get the next row in json format. The problem is when I use fetchAll to get all the countries from the database. I can use print_r to see the results of the query and everything is as expected but when I  use json_encode I get a blank screen. This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

With:

```
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
```

Comment: i m using new PDO('firebird:dbname='.$dados_sql['ip'].':'.$dados_sql['alias'].';charset=utf8',$pwEuser['pw'], $pwEuser['user']); and FECH_ASSOC, not FETCH_OBJ

Answer (score 4):

**When you have a problem with JSON**, there is a function `json_error()`.

After learning that there is a problem with encoding, tell your database to return data in `utf8`:

```
$_db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$data = $_db->query("SELECT * FROM countries")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header("content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to setup the charset at PDO initialization like this

```
$_db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8;", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Note the end of the first parameter above `charset=UTF8;`

Answer (score -1):

fetchall documentation says retrieves an array of all fetch data simutaneously. In this case, It seems your fetchall function assigned result array into arraylist.

Here is the reference link below,

[PDO fetch / fetchAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075954/pdo-fetch-fetchall)